# Ant 1.8.4 failing to resolve refid from another file - but Ant 1.6 was fine

Tags: ant, build

I was building ok on Java 6 and Ant 1.6, but I am now on Java 7 and Ant 1.8.4 and having a few problems. I've overcome quite a few but there is one that I'm stuck on.

I have a file containing some common targets, common.xml (containing just targets - no xml version string or projects):

```
<target name="common_init">
    <path id="project.class.path">
        ... stuff
    </path>
</target>
```

and two build files:
buildfile1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
    <!ENTITY common SYSTEM "file:./common.xml">
]>

<project name="proj1" default="main" basedir=".">
    <!-- import common targets using a xml entity definition -->
    &common;
    ...
    <target name="compile" depends="common_init">
        <javac
            srcdir="..." destdir="..." debug="on" deprecation="off" optimize="on" includes="**/*.java" source="${javac.target}" target="${javac.target}">

            <src path="..."/>
            <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    ...
</project>
```

That works fine. But an almost identical second build file gives me the error:

```
Reference project.class.path not found.
```

The second build file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
    <!ENTITY common SYSTEM "file:./common.xml">
]>

<project name="proj1" default="main" basedir=".">
    <!-- import common targets using a xml entity definition -->
    &common;
    ...
    <target name="compile" depends="common_init">
        <javac
            srcdir="..." destdir="..." debug="on" deprecation="off" optimize="on" includes="**/MyFile.java" source="${javac.target}" target="${javac.target}">

            <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    ...
```

I thought (clutching at straws) that the same project name may be the issue, but no. Both buildfiles are kicked off from a higher level build file using:

```
<ant antfile="buildfileX.xml"...>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code I had in my original post was just pseudo code, and I omitted the vital difference that was causing the problem, for which I apologise.

The build file that is working is as in my original post. The one that is failing is also as posted, but it is called slightly differently:

```
<project name="proj1" default="main" basedir=".">
    <!-- import common targets using a xml entity definition -->
    &common;
    ...
    <target name="compile" depends="common_init">
        <antcall target="compile1"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile1" depends="">
        <javac
            srcdir="..." destdir="..." debug="on" deprecation="off" optimize="on" includes="**/MyFile.java" source="${javac.target}" target="${javac.target}">

            <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    ...
</project>
```

So there must have been a change between Ant 1.6 and 1.8.4 where the default inheritance between tasks has changed. What a ridiculous change to have made. It can only cause people (people like me!!) problems. Anyway, hopefully this post will help others that encounter the same issue.

Paul

Comment: It's quite unclear what the cause of the error was, and what your fix is. Actual explanations of what was incorrect in the build file, vs what works, would be quite helpful.